# How to add new nominal values to Instances using AddValues?

Tags: java, weka

I really have to chew on the WEKA API.. All I want to do is to introduce new nominal values to my attributes.

I have data like **Sentence 1**

```
@relation i-do-not-care

@attribute sentence_id {1090587:0}
@attribute word {here,girlfriend,bday,23rd,go,for,my,just}
@attribute relations {nmod:poss-,amod+;nsubj-,nsubj+;nmod+;advmod+,amod-,nmod-;case+;nmod:poss+,advmod-,case-}
@attribute target {0}

@data
1090587:0,go,nsubj+;nmod+;advmod+,0
1090587:0,my,nmod:poss-,0
```

and **Sentence 2**

```
@relation i-do-not-care

@attribute sentence_id {1090587:1}
@attribute word {be,idea,house,weehawken,offer,view,top,along,of,have,if,you,a,in,the,ever,to,river,chart}
@attribute relations {aux-,cop-,nmod-;case+,nsubj+;acl:relcl-;xcomp+,advmod-,det-,nsubj-,advcl+;nsubj+;dobj+,case-,acl:relcl+;det+;nmod+;dobj-,mark+;nsubj+;det+;nmod+;cop+;aux+;case+;advcl-;advmod+,compound+;nsubj-;det+,mark+;xcomp-,mark-,compound-,det+;nmod+;nmod-;case+}
@attribute target {0,1}

@data
1090587:1,a,det-,0
1090587:1,have,advcl+;nsubj+;dobj+,0
```

And what I try to accomplish is adding those to an empty Instance dataset:

```
@relation features

@attribute sentence_id {}
@attribute word {}
@attribute relations {}
@attribute target {0,1}

@data
```

This is how I tried to do that:

```
public Instances add(Instances instances, Instances newInstances) {

    AddValues addValues = new AddValues();

    try {   
        // This should just copy 'sentence_id' values   
        // but I am not sure about that.            
        addValues.setAttributeIndex("1");
        addValues.setInputFormat(newInstances);

        instances = Filter.useFilter(instances, addValues); 

        return instances;               
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

but it's just overwriting `instances` instead of adding the values.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same code twice.

```
instances = Filter.useFilter(instances, addValues); 

return instances = Filter.useFilter(instances, addValues);
```

Try this:

```
instances = Filter.useFilter(instances, addValues); 

return instances;
```

Or the next level:

```
return Filter.useFilter(instances, addValues
```

Comment: Sorry, this was just a remainder of the actual code. I just simplified it and forgot to remove the second `useFilter()` call

Comment: Btw: I already "*managed*" to do the *add* part but it seems that AddValues does not take care about indexing or something because the data is just getting effed-up .. still waiting for someone knows how to do it *right*.